# Image Change with Drop-down selection-PLEASE ASSIST-No One is on Any Other Forum

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

[Picture of idea options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlOw1.jpg) I’ve attached a photo. This will be the best way to describe what I need to do, but I’ll try explaining with words. I’m not proficient in code language, coding, WP, GF, etc, so please excuse me if I’m confusing and speak to me like I'm 2. I won't take offense.

I am building an e-commerce website for my company using WordPress. I am a dealer for an LED company. I have permission to use every image, video, info from their site. I don’t want to copy their site, but I do like how their images change once you select an option in their dropdown list. Can you please tell me how to do this with GF without having to buy additional plugins besides product add-ons? I’ve watched a video showing this option using only the product add-ons, but he doesn’t explain how the images change; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cbcFjaIaGyQ&t=184s

Hopefully that wasn’t too confusing. Thank you in advance for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Woocommerce does have this as a default option. You just need to create a variable product. Set attributes and add them to variations. Then for each variation you can add different image, prices, quantity etc.

You can find a better detailed explanation on this [link](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/woocommerce/product-variations/)